# wrapping a callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have two corresponding lists: `addresses` and `descriptions`.

In JS, I'm using a 3rd-party API method: `Foo(addresses, FooCallback);`

I wrote a `FooCallback` that gets an array of `gecodings`. I want to match any `gecoding[i]` with `description[i]` inside my `FooCallback`. What is the best design to do so?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: what type of object is stored in your geocoding array and your description array?  Are we matching strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to save the state of `i`:

```
var addresses = [...stuff...];
var destinations = [...stuff...];
var i = 3; // maybe from a loop
var FooCallback = (function(destinations, index) {
    return function (geocodings, index) {
        if (geocodings[index] === destinations[index]) {
            // stuff;
        }
    }
})(destinations, i);

Foo(addresses, FooCallback);
```